# Makefile : how to create global variable available to sub-makefile?

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

Given a `master.makefile` calling a sub-makefile such :

```
downloads:
    make -f downloads.makefile
```

And a sub-makefile `downloads.makefile` such :

```
download: clean
    curl -o ./data/<itemname>.png 'http://www.mysite.com/<itemname>.png'
    echo "downloaded <itemname>: Done!"
```

**How to set a global variable `itemname` in my masterfile, available to my sub-makefile ?**

Note: My project is actually more complex, with 12 different sub-makefile, which should reuse the same parameters/variable from the master file. The masterfile should assign the value, while the sub-makefile should retrive the variable's value where I put `<itemname>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways to do it.

First, always, always use `$(MAKE)` and never `make` when running a sub-make. Then...

**1.** You can pass the value on the recursive command line:

```
itemname = whatever
downloads:
        $(MAKE) -f downloads.makefile itemname=$(itemname)
```

**2.** You can export the variable in the parent makefile:

```
export itemname = myvalue
downloads:
        $(MAKE) -f downloads.makefile
```

with sub-makefile such :

```
download: 
    echo "downloaded $(itemname): Done!"
```

Comment: For way **2.**, in the sub-makefile, I should use `$(itemname)` right ?

Comment: Yes... you always have to use that form (or `${itemname}` which is identical) when accessing make variables.

Comment: I'm half-tempted to down-vote this on the principle that [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf), but that would just be unnecessary ;)

Comment: Recursive make is sometimes the best way to do things.  While that paper is very good and raises some excellent points, I simply don't agree with the idea that as a result recursive make should _NEVER_ be used.  The main thrust of that paper is that recursive make chops up the DAG, which is true... but in some cases that's perfectly acceptable because what the recursive make is doing isn't really part of the DAG (or, is only a DAG leaf not an inner node) anyway, and getting the same behavior without recursive make gives gross and hard-to-maintain makefiles.